# Co-routine Wrapper not executing callback in a timely manner

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Okay so I have a pretty good idea of how to use co-routines in Unity3d 
but I want to make a reusable component for deferred execution that allows me to 
take code like this

```
StartCoroutine(WaitForDamageCooldown(DamageCooldown));

IEnumerator WaitForDamageCooldown(float duration)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
    HasTempInvincibility = false;
}
```

Taking that and convert it to something like this

```
CoroutineUtil.DeferredExecutor(float waitTime,Action onComplete);
```

To be used like this

```
StartCoroutine(CoroutineUtil.DeferredExecutor(WaitTime, () =>
{
    Debug.Log("DeferredExecutor wait complete");
    HasTempInvincibility = false;
}));
```

I've tried implementing that in the following

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public static class CoroutineUtil
{
    public static IEnumerator DeferredExecutor(float waitDuration, Action onComplete)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitDuration);
        onComplete.Invoke();
    }

    public static IEnumerator DeferredExecutor<T>(float waitDuration, T obj, Action<T> onComplete)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitDuration);
        onComplete.Invoke(obj);
    }
}
```

thinking that that might not work as a static  I've also attempted to add it to the object's class like this

```
public class Player: MonoBehaviour
{
///....etc
    IEnumerator DeferredExecutor(float waitDuration, Action onComplete)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitDuration);
        onComplete.Invoke();
    }

///....etc
}
```

The results have been sporadic. I can't figure a rhyme or reason to when the co-routine completes but it does so well after the expected time.

Is there something wrong with my approach

Comment: the code should be ok. I'm using something very similar in my code and works perfectly. The only thing different is basically you explicitely call Invoke: have you tried the short form and see if it works? es. onComplete();

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot... great minds think alike i guess...

Comment: let me know I'm interested in that.

Comment: Okay so it turns out that in other code my game time was cranked down when I was using it for a slow down effect. It does work YA!!

Comment: good to know, it would be really strange otherwise.

Comment: @Terrance please explain what worked for you. I'm at a loss here as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does work but, like other coroutines in Unity3d it reflects time from the [Time.TimeScale](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html). So because of that 2 seconds isn't necessarily 2 seconds.(Which was my issue)

```
Time.TimesScale = 1.0f;
```

That being said the following is how I've been implementing it.

```
public static IEnumerator DeferredExecutor(float waitDuration, Action onComplete)
{
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitDuration);
  onComplete();
}
```

And this is how I've been using it.

```
StartCoroutine(CoroutineUtil.DeferredExecutor(2f, () =>
{
  _TimePause.OnPause();
  GameOverCanvas.enabled = true;
}));
```

This does work but make sure you remember the correct calling conventions. Specifically the
`StartRoutine`